# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've always had my component set up like this:

```
dataSource = new SequencesDataSource(this.sequencesService);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.paginator.page.subscribe(x => this.loadSequences());
    this.loadSequences()
    this.dataSource.length.subscribe(x => this.paginator.length = x);
  }

  loadSequences(): void {
    this.dataSource.loadSequences(this.paginator.pageIndex + 1, this.paginator.pageSize, '00', this.datiForm);
  }
```

But having it set up like this would give me this error: ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'. This error refers to a mat progress bar that is set to appear only when the `dataSource`'s `loadingSubject` is set to true

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async">
      <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    </div>
```

So I changed the code according to [this guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/) moving the `loadSequences` call in the `ngOnInit` because it is where the `loadingSubject` is set to true.

```
dataSource = new SequencesDataSource(this.sequencesService);
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadSequences();   
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.paginator.page.subscribe(x => this.loadSequences());
    this.dataSource.length.subscribe(x => this.paginator.length = x);
  }

  loadSequences(): void {
    this.dataSource.loadSequences(this.paginator.pageIndex + 1, this.paginator.pageSize, '00', this.datiForm);
  }
```

This solves the error but it creates the one I have now: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageIndex' of undefined. As I read on other questions, `ViewChild` still isn't taken in at the time of `ngOnInit` so that's why `paginator` is undefined, how can I solve that?

Here's the `SequencesDataSource` with `loadSequences` method:

```
export class SequencesDataSource implements DataSource<Sequence> {

    private sequencesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Sequence[]>([]);

    private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

    public length = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    constructor(private sequencesService: SequencesService/*,
                private ripeService: RipeService*/) {

    }

    loadSequences(pageIndex: number,
                  pageSize: number,
                  rrc: string,
                  datiForm: FormComponent): void {

        this.loadingSubject.next(true);

        if (datiForm.sequenceId != null && datiForm.sequenceId !== ''){
            this.sequencesService.getSequence(datiForm.sequenceId).pipe(
                finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
            finalize(() => this.length.next(1)),
            map(sequence => [sequence]),
            tap(sequence => this.sequencesSubject.next(sequence))
        )
        .subscribe();
        }
        else{
        this.sequencesService.findSequences(pageIndex, pageSize, rrc, datiForm).pipe(
                finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
                tap(x => this.length.next(x.total))
            )
            .subscribe((sequences: PaginatedResult) => {
            this.sequencesSubject.next(sequences.items);
        }); }
    }
```

Comment: Anything related to ViewChild should be used after `ngAfterViewInit`, so maybe you can defer the `loadSequences()` call until 'ngAfterViewInit()'

Comment: That's how I had my component set up until now, the project worked but it gave an error, the one mentioned in the question, in the dev console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to use `setTimeout` to defer the code in `ngAfterViewInit` to another JavaScript turn:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {this.paginator.page.subscribe(x => this.loadSequences());
                      this.loadSequences();
                      this.dataSource.length.subscribe(x => this.paginator.length = x);
    });
  }
```

This will make this error disappear: ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.